# formula to convert the closing price of a forex pair to that of its inverse pair

Tags: pine-script, inverse

is there a formula to convert the closing price of a forex pair such as AUDCAD to the inverse pair CADAUD pls?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Great question
Not that I'm aware of unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

https://www.xignite.com/faqs/cryptocurrency-and-fx-rates/why-does-the-inverse-of-usdeur-not-equal-to-eurusd-or-any-2-currency-pairs/

Actually it's as simple as `1/close` to get the inverse pair value :)